# ANTLR - how to skip missing tokens in a 'for' loop

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm developing a 'toy' language to learn antlr.

My construct for a `for` loop look like this.

`for(4,10){
 //program expressions
};`

I have a grammar that I think works, but it's a little ugly. Specifically I'm not sure that I've handled the semantically unimportant tokens very well.

For example, the comma in the middle there appears as a token, but it's unimportant to the parser, it just needs the 2 and the 3 for the loop bounds. This means when I see the `child()` elements for the parts of the `loop` token, I have to skip the unimportant ones.

You can probably see this best if you examine the ANTLR viewer and look at the parse tree for this. The red arrows point to the tokens I think are redundant.

[image]

Feel like I should be making more use of the `skip()` feature than I am, but I can't see how to insert into the grammar for the tokens at this level.

`loop: 'for(' foridxitem ',' foridxitem  '){' (programexpression)+ '}';
foridxitem: NUM     #ForIndexNumÌ
              |
            var     #ForIndexVar;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Antlr produces a parse-tree, so there will always be cruft to step over or otherwise ignore when walking the tree.

The longer answer is that there is a tension between skipping cruft in the lexer and producing tokens of limited syntactic value that are nonetheless necessary for writing unambiguous rules.

For example, you identify `for(` as a candidate for skipping, yet is probably syntactically required. Conversely, the parameters comma could be truly without syntactic meaning.  So, you might clean it up in the lexer (and parser) this way:

```
FOR: 'for(' -> pushMode(params) ;
ENDLOOP: '}' ;
WS: .... -> skip() ;

mode params;
NUM: .... ;
VAR: .... ;
COMMA: ',' -> skip() ;
ENDPARAMS: '){' -> skip(), popMode() ;
P_WS: .... -> skip() ;
```

Your parer rule then becomes

```
loop: FOR foridxitem* programexpression+ ENDLOOP ;
foridxitem: NUM | VAR ;
programexpression: .... ;
```

That should clean up the tree a fair bit.